# Inline Image also gets Attached

Tags: python, email-attachments

I have a Python script for sending email with a varying numbers of inline images, and it's actually working as intended with one exception. Each image is also sent as an attachment, making each one appear twice. Even after disabling many parts of the script I've been unable to find what is causing the duplication.

```
 !/usr/bin/python
   coding: utf-8

   import os, sys
   import mimetypes
   from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
   from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
   from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
   from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
   from email import encoders import smtplib

   try:
 strTo = ‘’’Joe@Email.com’’’
 strFrom = ‘’’Jim@Some.biz’’’

 msg = MIMEMultipart()
 msg['Subject'] = ‘’’Photo Test’’’
 msg['From'] = '''Jim@Some.biz'''
 msg['Reply-to'] = '''Jim@Some.biz'''
 msg['To'] = ‘’’Joe@Email.com’’’
 msg.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

 # Encapsulate the plain and HTML versions of the message body in an
 # 'alternative' part, so email agents can decide which they want to display.
 msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
 msg.attach(msgAlternative)
 msgText = MIMEText(''' words here, then the image followed by more words here''', 'plain')
 msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
 msgText = MIMEText('''<p>words here, then the image</p><p><img src="cid:image1"></p><p>followed by more words here</p><p></p>''','html')
 msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
 # Attach Any Images
 if '''/Users/jim/Desktop/003.jpg''' != "":
     images = '''/Users/jim/Desktop/003.jpg'''.splitlines()
     i=1
     for image in images:
         # print 'Image',i,': ',image,'\n'
         fp = open(image, 'rb')
         msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
         fp.close()
         # Define the image's ID as referenced above
         msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image'+str(i)+'>')
         msg.attach(msgImage)
         i+=1

  #send the email
 smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(‘’’mailserver.net''', '''465''') 
 smtp.ehlo() 
 smtp.login('''Jim@Some.biz''', ‘’’xxxxxx’’’)
 smtp.sendmail(strFrom,strTo.split(","), msg.as_string())
 smtp.quit() except: print("Sending Error : "+strTo)
```

How can I prevent the image attachments?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, once found:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
```

should be

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
```